# join two repository pattern with getwithinclude method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, automapper, unit-of-work

I am learning UnitofWork, Repository pattern and in the genericrepository file I have a method like this and I am not sure how to use that in real example.

```
/// <summary>
/// Include multiple
/// </summary>
/// <param name="predicate"></param>
/// <param name="include"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetWithInclude(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity,
bool>> predicate, params string[] include)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.DbSet;
    query = include.Aggregate(query, (current, inc) => current.Include(inc));
    return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

for example if we have two repositories rep1,rep2 with a foreignkey relationship will this join two repositories and output it to a list, i know how to get the details from single repository.

```
public IEnumerable<CREntity> GetAllCR()
{
    var mapper = CreateMapper();
    var CRAll = _unitOfWork.Rep1.GetAll().ToList();
    //var joinFD = _unitOfWork.Rep1.GetWithInclude(); ---how to add Rep2 using getwithinclude
    if (CRAll.Any())
    {
        var CRModel = mapper.Map<List<ChangeRequest>, List<CREntity>>(CRAll);
        return CRModel;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Looks like all you need to do is `var data = Rep1.GetWithInclude(x => x.ID == 5, "ChildEntity1", ChildEntity2);`

Comment: Thank you for the response, one clarification is what is childentity1 and childentity2... are they the entityclass names Rep1 and Rep2 or the FK name ?

Comment: `Include` must contain navigation property names of the class `CREntity`, not repository names.

Answer (score 0):

this is a example in my code:

```
public List<TblUser> GetUserListWithRoles()
{
    GenericRepository<TblUser> repository = new GenericRepository<TblUser>(_context);

    List<TblUser> userList = new List<TblUser>();
    string[] includes = { "TblUserRol", "TblUserRol.FkIdRolNavigation" };
    userList = repository.GetWithInclude(c => c.State == true, includes).ToList();

    return userList;
}
```